# Getting id of dynamically created element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am generating some input fields with a drop-down list. I now want the text entered into those input fields to automatically update a span. But, as the input fields are dynamically generated I'm having a hard time getting it to work with jQuery

Thanks for any help!

HTML:

```
<div id="url">
    https://api.test.com<span id="endpoint" readonly="readonly"> </span>
</url>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Endpoint</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="dropdown" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
        <option value = "none">select</option>
            <option value="id">/test/{id}</option>
            <option value="id_date">/test/{id}/{date}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function(){
    $('#textBoxContainer').empty();
    var data = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    var cleaned_data = data.split("_");
    var num_args = cleaned_data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < num_args; i++){
        $('#textBoxContainer').append('<label class="control-label" for="textinput">' + cleaned_data[i] + '</label><br/><input id="' + cleaned_data[i] + '" name="textinput" size="25" type="text" placeholder="'+ cleaned_data[i] +'" class="input-xlarge"><br/>');
    }

});

jQuery('#date').on('input', function() {
    $('#endpoint').html('test');
})
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jangoforhire/pgHvV/1/)

Comment: You don't need an ID to select an element. `$("#textBoxContainer input")` will select all inputs that are descendants of `textBoxContainer`

Comment: What is `#endpoint_curl`? What is your task? what you need to achieve with this code?

Comment: `</url>` is all but not a vaild tag

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan That was a typo, I edited it above and in the Fiddle. Read the first few lines. It's designed to update the text in the span in real time with the text entered into one of the dynamically created input fields.

Comment: @tknickman gotcha, I already fixed it all in my answer's demo link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pgHvV/4/)**

```
$("#textBoxContainer").on('input','#date', function () {
    $('#endpoint').html(this.value);
});
```

Read the docs about the `.on()` method and event delegation for ***dynamically generated elements***

Comment: I believe `#date` is the dynamic part

Comment: Great, thank you. I was trying it with "live" earlier so I was close.

Comment: @tknickman yes, `live` was, the now deprecated, method to achieve the same.

Comment: I mean it should probably be something like `$('#textBoxContainer').on('input', 'input', function(){  ...`

Comment: @zgood yes, `document` is a bit expensive, an static `#ID` element is the way to go.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ok fair enough, I understand

Comment: why didn't you use `$(this).val()` ? is there any problem with that.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy wherever you can, use pure JS, it's **faster** and in such cases even more readable in combination with jQ i.e: `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr("id")` ... Agree? More interesting reading: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Answer (score 0):

you can create the element and assign the function at the same time

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pgHvV/6/)

```
        $('#textBoxContainer').append( 
            $("<input/>", 
              {
                type: "text", id: cleaned_data[i],
                name: "textinput", size:25, 
                placeholder: cleaned_data[i], 
                class:"input-xlarge", 
                keyup: function inputkeyup(){
                    $("#endpoint").text(this.value);
                }
            })
        ).append("<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/pgHvV/7/

Comment: You are doing your code slightly wrong. Here is the updated js fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/pgHvV/7/

Answer (score 0):

do everything inside your for loop...
you can create and manipulate and make use of controls and their values inside itself...

check for that

`for (var i = 0; i < num_args; i++){
        $('#textBoxContainer').append('<label class="control-label" for="textinput">' + cleaned_data[i] + '</label><br/><input id="' + cleaned_data[i] + '" name="textinput" size="25" type="text" placeholder="'+ cleaned_data[i] +'" class="input-xlarge"><br/>');
    /*do everything here.. you can create a on click on onchange or onblur or on anything for that id....*/ }`